# The date is not updated in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When trying to update the date inside the **MongoDB** document, nothing is updated.

To update, I send a request to **NodeJS** like this:

```
collection.updateOne(
   { _id: ObjectId(...) },
   { $set: { 'field1.field2.0.date': new Date('2020-02-01T00:00:00Z') } },
   callback
)
```

The task uses the npm package **mongodb@2.3.26** and **MongoDB 3.6.20**.

I tried to send the **'2020-02-01T00:00:00Z'** as a value - it is not updated. I tried to update the database version - it didn't help. I tried to update the driver version - it didn't help.

It is interesting that such a request goes through **Robo3T** and updates the value correctly.

[image]

Could you please tell me how to update the date inside the document for MongoDB?

---

UPD: Structure of document

```
const document = {
    field1: {
        exp: 1,
        field2: [
            {
                name: "test",
                date: 2019-10-01 00:00:00.000Z
            }
        ]
    },
    settings: {
        sharedTill: 2022-10-01 00:00:00.000Z
    },
    updatedBy: 'Vadim Prokopchuk'
}
```

---

UPD2: Added Response from MongoDB

MongoDB returned data and does not return an error.

[image]

Comment: can you show the structure of document (all fields)?

Comment: have you tried putting some logs into callback? most probably the error is dropped (for some reason) and the document is not updated. the document structure is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax you're using isn't correct.
Refer the query below, it would work

```
collection.updateOne(
   { _id: ObjectId(...) , 'field1.field2.name':"test"},
   { $set: { 'field1.field2.$.date': new Date('2020-02-01T00:00:00Z') } },
   callback
)
```

Here, we are finding the element of the array which matches our condition and then updating the date of that particular element of the array.

Comment: Why my request successfully completed in Robo3T if I used incorrect syntax?

Comment: It didn't find the matching element so just proceeded further.